# How to see output of cmake's add_custom_command

Tags: cmake, console

The add_custom_command is lisently failing if run from CMakeLists.txt
Is there a way to see in console what's happening when the command is executed?

EDIT: The code:
I tried to run examples from the repository but they didn't work.
The code is modified a little because I was trying to make it work somehow. If the command is run from the terminal it works, but cmake just refuses to work. And there is no output saying why it fails.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(test LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt5Core)
find_package(Qt5Gui)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)


# Download automatically, you can also just copy the conan.cmake file
if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
   message(STATUS "Downloading conan.cmake from https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan")
   file(DOWNLOAD "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/conan-io/cmake-conan/master/conan.cmake"
                  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
endif()

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake)

conan_cmake_run(CONANFILE conanfile.txt
                BASIC_SETUP)

get_filename_component(hw_proto "protos/test.proto" ABSOLUTE)
get_filename_component(hw_proto_path "${hw_proto}" PATH)

# Generated sources
set(hw_proto_srcs   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/test.pb.cc")
set(hw_proto_hdrs   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/test.pb.h")
set(hw_grpc_srcs    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/test.grpc.pb.cc")
set(hw_grpc_hdrs    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/test.grpc.pb.h")

message("CHECKING GRPC.
        PROTOC: ${CONAN_BIN_DIRS_PROTOBUF}/protoc
        AND PLUGIN: ${CONAN_BIN_DIRS_GRPC}/grpc_cpp_plugin
        and lib dir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} from ${hw_proto}
        ${hw_proto_srcs}
        ${hw_proto_hdrs}
        ${hw_grpc_srcs}
        ${hw_grpc_hdrs}
        ${hw_proto}
        ${hw_proto_path}
        ")

add_custom_command(
      OUTPUT "${hw_proto_srcs}" "${hw_proto_hdrs}" "${hw_grpc_srcs}" "${hw_grpc_hdrs}"
      COMMAND ${CONAN_BIN_DIRS_PROTOBUF}/protoc
      ARGS --grpc_out="${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        --cpp_out="${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        --proto_path="${hw_proto_path}"
        --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="${CONAN_BIN_DIRS_GRPC}/grpc_cpp_plugin"
        test.proto
      )

add_executable(test
  main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(test Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Gui pthread)
target_include_directories(test PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

Comment: `make VERBOSE=1`?

Comment: didnt help...... =(

Comment: If `make VERBOSE=1` outputs nothing, then probably you custom command is not executed at all, or it itself outputs nothing. For being able to help you, we need more detailed description of your problem, which includes the code (in form of [mcve]) and output which that code gives.

Comment: Nothing depends on OUTPUT of your custom command, so its COMMAND is not executed at all. The simplest way is to add all files, specified as OUTPUT for the command, to the `add_executable` call.

Answer (score 0):

One way to see all commands being executed is to call `cmake` with the `--verbose` option.